# Subscriber User on WordPress Demo Site

Tags: wordpress, acl, demo-site, testing

I've been running into a few issues on my CiviCRM installs that would be nice to test against the demo site.  However, because there is no subscriber level user on the demo, and I can't seem to create one, I'm unable to test.  (I don't expect to have the ability to create users.  That sounds like a bad idea.)  Would it be possible to have a user at each WordPress level that could be used for testing, especially when dealing with situations where ACL's come into play?